# Is there a safe space to ask questions seeking feedback?

Tags: discussion

Questions seeking feedback about any topic, are, by definition, opinion seeking questions, and questions that could lead to opinionated answers are discouraged on Stack Exchange sites.

However, on many of the meta sites, the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag seems to allow it, though, there's a part that concerns me (*emphasis mine*):

> *The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions, influence site policy, or debate a particular topic, **with the goal of reaching a community consensus**.*

When asking a question that seeks general feedback, is the intent really to seek a community consensus? If not, then wouldn't that qualify the question as *off-topic*?

---

With that, is there a safe space to ask questions seeking feedback? Examples could include requests for feedback on a new addon or modification for a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta sites do not have the same rules about what questions are acceptable. Discussion and opinion questions are discouraged on **main** Stack Exchange sites, but they are accepted on meta sites, as indicated by the quoted description of the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.

If you want a discussion about something related to a game, you can discuss it in chat, or try a different website like Reddit.

Comment: Note: the question links to `[tag:discussion]` but my answer links to `[meta-tag:discussion]`. That's why they look different and point to different pages.

Comment: I was wondering why my tag took me to the main site.